# jQuery DatePicker prevent input on other controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, datepicker

I want to prevent input on other controls than the active [jQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (active datepicker = focus on its textbox **or** open calendar) until I have validated the date with a script.

I tried to do this by preventing blur, which works fine when you tab out of the field. But when, for example, a user clicks a checkbox, this checkbox will be checked/unchecked before the blur event is fired on the DatePicker textbox.

This was my original plan, with asp.net validators (a custom validator for valid dates and a custom validator to test the daterange):

```
$('#myCalendar').blur(function(){
    return Page_ClientValidate('myValidationGroup');
});
```

How can I prevent the input on the other controls while the chosen/typed date is invalid, without putting checks on the other controls? I prefer not to disable every other control.

**Update:**
It seems that an alert will cancel out the event on the other control. Now, why is that and can I use this to my advantage in a way that doesn't need the alert?

Comment: i think, `blur` event fires first than `click` event. please have a look at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bSfT2/

Comment: @Mohit, it seems you are right. But why does the state of my checkbox still alter when Page_ClientValidate returns false?

Answer (score 0):

This is as good as I can get it myself a.t.m., suffient for now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.DatePicker:text").on("blur.MyNamespace", function () { return dp_FireValidators(this, null); });
});

var rewriteHandlers = 'click.MyNamespace, dblclick.MyNamespace, change.MyNamespace, focusin.MyNamespace, keydown.MyNamespace, keypress.MyNamespace, mousedown.MyNamespace';
function dp_FireValidators(sender, args) {
    $(sender).removeClass('CalenderInvalidDate');

    if (sender.Validators.length > 0) {
        var vGroup = sender.Validators[0].validationGroup;

        if (vGroup == undefined)
            Page_ClientValidate();
        else
            Page_ClientValidate(vGroup);

        for (var i = 0; i < sender.Validators.length; i++) {
            if (!sender.Validators[i].isvalid) {
                dp_PreventChangesWhileDateIncorrect();
                $(sender).addClass('CalenderInvalidDate');
                $(sender).focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    $("input:checkbox, select").off(rewriteHandlers);

    return true;
}

function dp_PreventChangesWhileDateIncorrect() {
    $("input:checkbox, select").on(rewriteHandlers, function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Only a dblclick on a checkbox in IE will slip through.

Answer (score 0):

> The blur event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. Therefore,
>   scripts that rely on event delegation with the blur event will not
>   work consistently across browsers. As of version 1.4.2, however,
>   jQuery works around this limitation by mapping blur to the focusout
>   event in its event delegation methods, .live() and .delegate().

This is from the [jquery api documentation](https://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Have you tried using a custom client side validator?

We put this code in our global core.js file.

```
function dateValidator(source, arguments) {
    var d = new Date(arguments.Value);
    return arguments.IsValid = !isNaN(d.valueOf());
}
```

then use a Custom validator calling the script.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvInstallationDate" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Installation Date."
                            ControlToValidate ="txtInstallationDate" EnableClientScript="true" ClientValidationFunction ="dateValidator">
                            <img src='/Images/WarningIcon.png' width='16' height='16' title='Invalid Installation Date' />
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: I am using a custom validator, but this doesn't prevent users from clicking other controls (which can have the autopostback turned on).